# Within a regular R project, is it possible to paste images into .qmd files (with automatic file-saving as in Quarto books)?

Tags: r, quarto

I know when pasting an image into a .qmd file within a Quarto book, the image is saved in docs/images.

When trying to do such a paste in a .qmd file within an R project, nothing happens. Is it possible to configure the same behaviour from Quarto book projects?